# Ошибка в переводе в баннере

Tags: дефект, локализация

Ошибка в "задаЙть вопрос"

[image: задаЙть вопрос]

Comment: А где этот баннер появляется? Я только именные вижу на главной.

Comment: @alexolut при просмотре вопроса в правой колонке под жёлтым featured блоком на основном SO, как бы реклама. ссылка на картинку https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/10437480827273323416

Comment: Ну надо на англомету и писать тогда, хехе :) Почему-то мне из неименных показывается только [синий баннер](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d99f.png), без опечатки.